# Swift App delegate->ViewController Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, swift, delegates, tableview, viewcontroller

I am currently developing a Cocoa application with swift. I want to update a tableview from the app delegate. I have a File->Open @Ibaction that causes data to be loaded from a file. I am unable to update the tableview in the view controller with this data. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have may have a document based app but didn't create your cocoa app as a document based app.  If so and you create your app as a document based app you get the infrastructure for all this stuff (and much much more - versioning, undo, resilience, etc) for free.  Have a read here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html